# QGIS Composer Prints Blank Page

Tags: qgis-2, print-composer

I am trying to print a map that I have made in QGIS print Composer. When I try to print the map or export it to a PDF (or any other format) as a raster all I get is a blank page. When I try to print not as a raster (unchecking the "print as raster option") it will print but obviosly not the way I want it to. eg. Layers arent transparent nor do other bits look right. I don't understand why this would happen. Why wont do I have a blank page when trying to print as a raster?

I am running QGIS 2.0 on a UBUNTU 13.10/64bit/16GiB ram

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Can you tell us how you created the map? Does it happen on every case?

Comment: Is it a WMS-layer that doesn't allow printing?

Comment: I have had similar issues when using an open layer base map. When I remove the base map I am able to print again. However, this is not consistent  and sometimes everything will print just the way I have it.